Use versioned Formatter, Inspections and Code Cleanup Configs in IntelliJ
I have configured an IntelliJ Formatter, Code Cleanup and Inspections Profile. I want to check in these profiles so my team members can use them. The problem is: They have to import these settings again if somebody changes the profiles.
Is there a way to just configure a path to the versioned files (for Formatter, Code Cleanup and Inspections) instead of importing them?
I know I can export the formatter settings to the .editorConfig and just use this file, but this won't solve my problem with the other profiles. Are there any options or plugins that solve this problem?
